# How can I find point geometry typed tables from postgis?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.5

I want to get all point geometry type tables from postgis. Can I use sql select for this operations.

I can select all tables from `select * from information_schema.tables` table.

And I can get all geometry columns like this:

```
SELECT type FROM geometry_columns;
```

This query returns "GEOMETRY"

But I want to select all tables hthat has POINT geometry type.

Comment: try `select distinct table_schema,table_name from information_schema.columns where data_type = 'point';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question right, you can just query it from `information_schema` with:

```
select distinct table_schema, table_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where data_type = 'point';
```

eg:

```
t=# create table p(i point);
CREATE TABLE
t=# select distinct table_schema,table_name from information_schema.columns where data_type = 'point';

 table_schema | table_name
--------------+------------
 postgres     | p
(1 row)
```

Comment: `select distinct table_schema,table_name 
from information_schema.columns where data_type = 'point';` returns nothing.